# Как сделать систему пользоватей (войти/выйти/региcтрация)?

Tags: html, javascript, css

Нужно реализовать с помощью HTML ,CSS, javascript;
Я работаю с denwer или openserver

Comment: Покупайте хостинг!!!

Comment: Как выйти в окно которого нет?

Comment: А написанно ведь - без сервера:)) Значит сайта ВООБЩЕ не будет:))))

Comment: Да, такое изменение своего вопроса - **это сильный ход!!!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Абсолютно никак.
Для того, чтобы пользователи могли регистрироваться и авторизовываться, их данные надо хранить централизованно, т.е. на сервере.
Иначе получится, что каждый пользователь типа зарегистрировался, типа авторизовался, но знает об этом только он сам (ну вернее его комп - локальное хранилище ж используем)

Comment: А если к примеру, хостинг поддерживает только HTML И CSS. То если очень надо, то можно реализовать, правда какова цена задачи будет - это другой вопрос.

Comment: Задача в принципе нерешаема только на HTML, CSS и JavaScript.
Если нет серверного хранилища данных, то это невозможно

Comment: Согласен насчет сервера, но есть вероятность, что автор может использовать хост, к примеру от narod2.yandex.ru

Answer (score 16):

> Как сделать систему пользоватей
> (войти/выйти/региcтрация)? Без сервера.

Никак.

Comment: Ну таки сразу и никак? :)

Можно по идее обработку данных повесить на JS и писать все в локальное хранилище. В принципе будет похоже на настоящую авторизацию/регистрацию. Однако какой в этом смысл, совершенно неясно. :)

Comment: Так сразу и никак. Локальное хранилище к вопросу не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: спасибо! я хотел палец вверх но не могу

Answer (score 5):

Соглашаюсь с Павлом. Можно реализовать базу данных как файл, но все-же советую приобрести платный хостинг, если у Вас нет денег на покупку хостинга (Хотя он стоит не так уж дорого) тогда зарегистрируйте бесплатный. Если Вам надо хороший хост и бесплатно, станьте сам себе хостингом( При условии что у вас ип адрес Ваш статический). Удачи

Comment: sps. а как реализововать помогите плиз

Comment: сам себе сервер? Если вы новичок рекомендую использовать сборку Apserver 2.5.9 или 2.6.0. Новее не ставьте они еще не доработанные. При установки вам придется указать папку где будет стоят сервер, имя хоста(например localhost), email и пароль к базе данных. Больше не чего там не трогайте, он настроен правильно. После чего в папке apserver/www/ - ваш контент, ссылка на ваш сайт http:// ваш ип / или http://127.0.0.1 ( Но по этой ссылки только вы сможете зайти)

Answer (score 3):

Если хотите, допустим, чтобы комментировали сайт, то можете подключить например [виджет комментариев вконтакте](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=Comments). Для работы виджета не нужен php, всё работает на js и html. Но комментировать в этом случае могут только пользователи вконтакте.

Comment: Ну да, работает.  Потому что серверной стороной, которая всё хранит, авторизует и т.п., является сайт вКонтакте